# Reinstalling GRUB2 on Ubuntu 12.04 | Windows 7 dual boot after Windows reinstallation

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, data-recovery

So I had the perfect Ubuntu 12 / Windows 7 dual boot set-up -- until I had to re-install Windows 7.

After the deed, GRUB2 was of course wiped out, thus my Ubuntu installation is rendered inaccessible.

I have tried these steps:

```
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt   #This is where my Ubuntu installation resides.
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot #Indicated by the `*` under `Boot` when doing `fdisk -l`
mount --bind /mnt/proc /proc
mount --bind /mnt/sys  /sys
mount --bind /mnt/dev  /dev
sudo chroot mnt
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
#Then unmounted everything...
```

Unfortunately, only my Windows 7 has been detected and the Ubuntu entries never appeared in the prompt. Only my Windows 7 installation (`/dev/sda1`) is available in the GRUB2 menu.

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is a great graphical and automatic utility to restore grub.

Try to use the [2nd option](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu) cuz is more quick.

Comment: I've been meaning to use this but opted not to. I have quite a specific set-up and I'm not quite sure which options to specify as to not ruin the Windows boot loader.

Comment: But you must "ruin" the Windows boot-loader. You have to replace it with Grub. You attempted to (in your original question) but failed. So try with this automatic tool.

Answer (score 0):

*Short Answer*: You don't need to mount sda1 unless it contains your Linux boot folder.  An easy way to check is to look at `/etc/fstab` after you chroot (or `/mnt/etc/fstab` before).

See if that makes any difference.

*Long answer*: If `sda1` is your Windows partition, mounting it to `/mnt/boot` will essentially hide your Linux boot files and so grub won't find them.